# Store and calculate running totals + moving averages with Realm

Tags: android, sum, window, realm, average

I'm making my first Android app, a running mileage stats app that includes miles run daily, weekly, monthly, yearly. along with cumulative averages for those categories. I'm using a Realm database to hold each instance of my `Run` objects that includes the number of miles run and the `Date` time it occurred.

What's the most efficient way to generate or organize those stats? It's possible to run through each `Run` saved in the database every time the app is opened and crunch the numbers, but I think it might be better to try to save this information in something like a persistent `Stats` object in the Realm database. I think this Stats objects would need the current average and the most recent date reflected in that number  (to know when it's appropriate to update them)

How can I efficiently group the `Run`s by week, month, year, etc? Best way I can think of is to get a `Calendar` object, setTime() on that calendar with a `Run.Date` object, and use the Calendar methods to compare if two `Run`s occurred in the same day, or week, or month, etc. Doesn't seem like it's very easy to manipulate and compare the `Date` objects by themselves.

```
public class Run extends RealmObject{
    private Date date;
    private double miles;

    public Run(){}

    public Run(Date date, double miles) {
        this.date = date;
        this.miles = miles;
    }


    //getters and setters
}
```

Hopefully I'm being clear enough in my descriptions. General information organization advice and best practices would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: By default, I think grouping them is pretty easy, considering defining the right RealmQuery gives you a list of runs, effectively a "group" by the "date" you specify as a lower and upper bound.

Comment: Right, so let's say I have a list of runs spanning 3 months. Do I have to manually query that list for each week in those 3 months? That didn't seem very efficient, but it might be the only way to do it

Comment: Realm doesn't support moving average (or any Savitzky-Golay filters) so you need to query manually. You are welcome to create an issue at our Github repository.